# Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in /var/www/mysite/includes/theme.inc on line 637

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

The error occurred when I am trying to customized my own login page in drupal, according to this source: [tutorial on how to customize and overriding login pages in drupal](https://www.drupal.org/node/350634)

And then I've been using `drush cc all` to clear the cache and somehow it appeared. I haven't done anything in the codes, since it is still working when I'm trying to apply it, and just to be sure, I traced back my edits and nothing seems wrong about it.

The line in 637 in mysite/includes/theme.inc

```
 // Merge the newly created theme hooks into the existing cache.
$cache = $result + $cache;
```

Comment: Seeing as the error is that the operand (in this case `+`) is not supported - maybe clearing the cache changed the type of `$cache` (to something like `null`?) and now the behavior of adding both types by `+` has changed. Try printing out the type of `$result` and `$cache`.

Comment: It simply states that `$result` , `$cache` are not having same datatype. that's why you are facing problem. try to `var_dump()` both value and check there datatype.

Comment: @anantkumarsingh `$result` is returning an array and a null while the other one is an array also. I guess they were not really in a same datatype. So what do I need to do make it the same? or restore it from before?

Comment: the returned array from both variables is too long to print in here.

Comment: Try this:- `if(isset($result) && !empty($result)){$cache = $result + $cache;}`

Comment: It works like charm! Thank you! I guess clearing the cache makes it null. so checking it if null makes it skip to make it initialize again. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It simply states that `$result` , `$cache` are not having same datatype. that's why you are facing problem. try to `var_dump()` both value and check there datatype.

As you stated in your comment based on that you need to do like below:-

`if(isset($result) && !empty($result)){$cache = $result + $cache;}`